# figuring out/refactoring this if/else for a voting system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, refactoring

I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how to do this in the best way possible without having an enormous if/else structure. I know i could do it that way but I'm trying to abstract it into methods and I'm lost.

```
upvote = 1
no vote = 0
downvote = -1
```

Basically, a person can hit an upvote or a downvote button.

If they click upvote and their current vote is upvote, it 'unvotes' the post and sets it to zero

if they click downvote and their current vote is upvote, it switches it to downvote

if their vote is zero, and they click upvote, it sets the vote to 1

The inverse is true for downvote

This is what i have so far but it doesnt account for clicking upvote after you already clicked upvote.. instead of setting it to 0 it sets it to -1.

I get the problem, im just having difficulty figuring out how to write it

```
  def update_vote(upvote_or_downvote)
    self.active_vote? ? self.value = 0 : self.alternate_vote
  end

  def active_vote?
    self.value != 0
  end

  def alternate_vote
    self.value *= -1
  end
```

Comment: “If they click upvote and their current vote is upvote, it 'unvotes' the post and sets it to zero” — this doesn't seem intuitive to me. I would expect clicking downvote would set it to zero, therefore I'd have to click downvote twice to set it to downvote.

Comment: i agree to disagree. i'm just following what reddit and lot of other voting sites do.

Comment: I wouldn't think of clicking on Upvote to cancel my up vote. I'd click on down vote. Seems to me your struggle to encapsulate your UI logic , is because it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Even stack overflow does it the way im trying to do it... youre on a site right now which has it exactly how i want it :P

Comment: @Tallboy Point taken. ;)

Comment: I think its hilarious after I said that I see my vote changing crazily... hehe

Comment: It does? There's a reason I didn't know that. So if you've upvoted boss what should it do if you click it again, foolishly presents list of options to boss. Manager throws a dice, chooses one....

Comment: what? that makes no sense... its how reddit, digg (i think?), stack overflow and a million other voting sites do it. I think you 'fail to see the logic'

Comment: Yes I do and seeing as the interface was designed for me to use. Is that failing mine or theirs? I've never intentionally clicked on upvote to downvote, never occurred to me to do so. Now that you've told me it does do this, I'm not going to use the facility as a matter of principle, so there!

Comment: Well, im not saying you're wrong, I'm saying thats what most people are used to because so many people do it that way... its like why does the save icon have a floppy on it? doesnt really make sense but its what people 'know' even if its not the 'best picture'.

Comment: by the way i think you misread, you dont click upvote to downvote. you click downvote to downvote. You click upvote a 2nd time if you want to 'undo' your upvote and just leave it at "no vote at all"

Comment: Ruby. Say they click upvote if their vote is upvote (1). If their current vote is upvote (1), active_vote? returns true so it runs alternate_vote which changes it to -1. it should switch it to 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do it. Here's one. I presume up_or_down will be passed as +1 for upvote and -1 for downvote. Don't overcomplicate things.

```
def update_vote(up_or_down)
  self.value = self.value == up_or_down ? 0 : up_or_down
end
```

It's simple if you think of the logic this way:
If user clicks same thing, reset to zero. Otherwise set it to the value clicked.

Comment: Yes in hindsight that logic explanation makes it very easy to write it. I dont know why that was so hard :S

Answer (score 1):

Toying with a state machine (it's easier than I thought):

```
require 'statemachine' #it's a gem

vote_state = Statemachine.build do
 #trans old_state, event, new_state
  trans :zero, :upvote, :up
  trans :zero, :downvote, :down
  trans :down, :upvote, :up
  trans :down, :downvote, :zero
  trans :up, :upvote, :zero
  trans :up, :downvote, :down
end

vote_state.upvote
p vote_state.state #=> :up
vote_state.upvote
p vote_state.state #=> :zero
vote_state.upvote
p vote_state.state #=> :up
vote_state.downvote
p vote_state.state #=> :down
```